# I have a RAID0 system drive pair (2 SSDs), Will Windows 10 upgrade ruin this?

Tags: raid-0

I have a RAID0 system drive pair (2 SSDs). Will Windows 10 upgrade ruin this?  I saw on this site where Win10 loused up a person's spanned drive D:, so now I'm worried about the upgrade.  I'm really glad I caught that post.  I hope someone can answer my question.

Comment: as always, back up first.

Comment: It's relevant to know what type of RAID0 you are using: do you have a RAID controller, or are you using software RAID? Would it be an option to remove RAID, upgrade to Win10 and then migratie to a RAID 10 configuration again?

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are using hardware RAID (from your motherboard?), since Windows will not let you use software RAID on the boot volume.  If this is the case, then there should be no issues.  As far as the OS is concerned, all it can actually see is one disk that is presented by the RAID controller.

Comment: "*It sounds like you are using hardware RAID*": I don't see that in the question. Also: not all hardware RAID might be supported by Windows 10. I've read cases where hardware drivers needed to be loaded before a RAID setup works during the installations of Windows.